# What type of lighting is used in this picture?

Tags: lighting

I just came across this picture . Would you guys know what LED's or lights have been used in this ?

[image]

Comment: That's *awfully* uniform lighting. Could be a photographic trick, really good diffusers with LED tape or similar, or possibly electroluminescent light strips: https://www.google.com/search?q=light+strip+electroluminescent&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=electroluminescent+tape

Answer (score 3):

Well, if we trust google's reverse image lookup, that's a picture of [3528 led light strips](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HSF66JO) in action.

The problem is, those light strips have emitters every 5/8", so it's my opinion that you're looking at a bit of photo trickery or a diffuser that isn't ordinarily a part of those kits.